# Appium: Getting error "Failed to start Chromedriver session, Original error: unknown error: Failed to get PID for the following process"

Tags: appium, appium-android

Got this error when I tested an Android build "internal" flavor, I believe the problem is a mismatch in package and process name of our Android application build which could have to happen when the package name changed due to the "internal" flavor. I'm still looking into how to fix this and I can find any relevant cases here and while searching on the web. I'll keep looking and trying fixes but if anyone has an idea or solution pls. let me know.

Comment: How have you set up? Sometimes this occurs, when you use older versions of chromedriver or if the device has older version of chrome or if the appium node installer is older.

Comment: Based on what you're saying it just sounds like you need to refactor your literal package and process names to variables.  It should only affect your webdriver creation capabilities settings and your page objects.

Comment: @Knight can you post full appium logs ?

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS My setup use latest Appium 1.9.0 with Genymotion emulator of Nexus 6 OS 7.1.

Comment: @BillHileman Yes i think the problem is around package name and/or process name of the Android application but i'm not sure what you mean about refactor, can you pls. elaborate

Comment: @Manidroid here's a stack of relevant appium log (actually how do you post a log cause this comment box does not allow longer texts?)

Comment: I saw this from appium log though that i think is relevant to the issue "2018-09-18 21:36:13:280 - [Chromedriver]   (process name must be specified if not equal to package name)"...Also this happens when i switch context to a webview.

Comment: By refactoring, I mean that instead of hard-coding the package names as literal text, assign them to variables or constants so that you only have to change them in one place and/or you can programmatically decide which package id's to use from available constants/variables.

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks for the additional info, we do have the package name as a variable in our code. In fact, we define this in a property file that we can update if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Findings**: Turns out that Android creates a new package name for every different "flavor" build, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants but retain the processName. In our case, it added "internal" on package name ex. com.xxxx.android.internal while processName remains com.xxxx.android.

**Issue**: The root of the issue is when you switch to webview context, Appium pass certain capabilities to ChromeDriver including packageName but when it tried to issue an adb command to find the process it can't find it because of a mismatch.

**Solution**: Use chromeOptions capability to pass the processName, see code below in java.

```
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("androidProcess", "com.xxxx.android"); 
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```